# Lyx problem I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, compiling

While trying to compile an old lyx file I worked on a while ago, I got the message

*I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file*

I came across the [following](https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2008-September/010814.html) link, which says that I should move the \bibliographystyle command before the \bibliography command. But I am not sure on how to do something like this in a lyx file. Does anybody know how I can do this? Or any other suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

edit ~ something else which I remembered is that this file is a tex file which was converted to lyx. Maybe it has to do with this. But still, can I fix it using lyx?

Comment: "I remembered is that this file is a tex file which was converted to lyx" … do you still have the original tex file? Have you make any significant edits since then? It might help diagnose the problem. Also, what does the TeX file you get if you export *from* LyX look like? Does it have both `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` commands, and is the latter before the former?

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for the advice. I no longer have the original tex file, but when I convert it from Lyx back to tex, the only bibliography related thing I see is \bibliography{GlobalBib_210709} (the command to use my bib file). This bib file works fine in other documents. There is also no \bibliographystyle command anywhere so I am not sure how I should move it.

Comment: I don't really know LyX very well. One the main reasons I avoid it is because the extra layer of complexity in between you and the result makes troubleshooting so much more difficult. Before you do anything I'd make a copy of the project so nothing gets permanently lost. Then I'd probably just try deleting and/or reinserting the bibliography through LyX's insert > list/toc menu. I would hope that would preserve the citations but I don't know.

Comment: You may be able to add the style just by right clicking on the bibliography and changing the settings (adding to the Style drop down). Or you may be to add it by adding `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to the document Preamble under Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble. (Change "plain" to whatever style you want to use.)

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have slove the problem?

Comment: @lusaty I was able to solve it, see solution below

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that somehow the problem had nothing to do with the bibliography. After starting to remove paragraphs from the document one by one, I discovered that the problem was with one of the images in the file, which was in a format that Lyx did not like. Once I removed it the notification stopped and the bibliography started appearing without any compilation errors.